# Edit imported animated model in GodotEngine3

Tags: godot

I've a 3d model that I've been clipped its animations and I wrote some scripts inside my game for it. Now some animations are changed and I want to just update my model. It's not good to clip all animations again each time the model changes!
I tried to...

- clip updated model animations and export it in another Godot project and import it to my project. But it doesn't imported any keyframe!
- import .dae file into the blender, but it seems corrupted!
- just replacing new .dae file over old one, the model became corrupted when I open my project in Godot.
- replacing new .dae file over old one and deleted all .import files, Godot project will become corrupted after re(import) the updated assets.

We're really in trouble with it and I don't know what to do with it! Is it an unhandled problem in Godot? We're in the last steps of our game production!!

Comment: Do you have a saved .blend file from before you exported as a .dae file?